# Free GUI editor

Tags: user-interface, editor

Could someone please advise a free GUI editor (GUI designer)?

This question was asked before but it concerned an editor that could create programming code.

I don't need to create any programming code. I need to write a specification for the customer with some images representing the interface of the future program.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What operating system? GUIs are rather OS dependent.

Comment: @everyone who answered. I think he's looking for some prototyping software, not something that generates full-blown application code.

Comment: @Tergiver good comment. The number one reason I mentioned Interface Builder is because Andrey is doing Java development, while not mentioning this in the question. :)

Comment: If you're using Eclipse wireframesketcher (paying iirc) could be useful (http://wireframesketcher.com/) for creating mockups of User Interfaces.

Comment: For web apps. The interface will be created using GXT (sencha.com) mainly.

Comment: @Andrey web apps should be written in HTML, not?

Comment: @ChristopheD Thanks! It seems my question is incorrect. I need some prototyping software like WireframeSketcher you mentioned (you may post a separate answer to my question).

Comment: @Time Machine not really, I use GWT. Please visit sencha.com if you are interested.

Comment: @Andrey ahah. I normally use HTML with jQuery for my web apps, with a Ruby or a PHP backend. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Eclipse wireframesketcher (a paying program iirc) could be useful ([wireframesketcher.com](http://wireframesketcher.com/)) for creating mockups of User Interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

- [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/xcode.html), an excellent IDE includes a GUI designer called Interface Builder.
- [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) is also a good one if you meant 'Free' as in 'Freedom' instead of 'Free of charge.'
- Visual Basic
- Visual C#
- Visual C++
- DreamWeaver
- Visual Basic for Applications
- Pen and paper

Answer (score 1):

GUI editor for Java in NetBeans, QT Creator, Glade for Gnome, Delphi - there are lots of 'em. I believe the choice mostly depends on your needs in programming area.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans is an excellent IDE. You can easily design your interfaces using Matisse, look at the interfaces, show the results and do no use the code if you don't need it. It is free and runs on many platforms (Linux, Win, Mac). You can use it for Java, C++, PHP, you name it...

Answer (score 0):

1. [Mono](http://monodevelop.com/)
2. [Sharp](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/)